# USB host has confusing documentation

Tags: android, android-intent, usb

I am working with the Android Host mode for USB.  In the documentation for the [host mode api](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html), the manifest requirements suggest using:

```
android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED
```

This is causing me some confusion as the [UsbManager docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html#ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED) suggest using:

```
android.hardware.usb.action.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED
```

Can someone explain the difference between the two?

Furthermore, the UsbManager (2nd) version does not inform my app when the device is attached, but the host (1st) version does.

I also cannot get the detached intent to work using either version:

```
android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED
android.hardware.usb.action.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED
```

please advise.

**Edit**

Here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cs.android.terminal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />


    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
         >


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />                
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />                    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />


        </activity>

        <receiver             
            android:name="cs.android.terminal.TerminalReceiver"
            android:exported="false"
            >
           <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />                
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` is to be used in your Manifest file to detect when a device is attached to USB. `ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` is to be used with in you java code to indicate that an action is performed and what that action is. Although there is currently an error/bug with `ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` where Android does not detect that BroadcastReceiver within the java code, it can only be detected within your manifest currently. All that said, use `USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` in your manifest.

**EDIT:** Try this:

```
 <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
```

Comment: Okay, I guess that helps me a little.  Would you happen to know then why the detach filter is not receiving the detach broadcast event?

Comment: Have you registered your `BroadcastReceiver`? Usually this is done in `onResume` though for USB communications I did it in the `onCreate` and then I would call the `unregisterReceiver` in the `onDestroy`, but that is normally done in `onPause`.

Comment: Both receivers are registered in the manifest: one for attach and one for detach.  the attach filter works fine, but detach never fires.

Comment: Hmmm... I've actually worked with the Accessory mode, not Host/Device Mode, but there are a lot of similarities. I have my `USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED` in the manifest, but then I have my `USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED` done programatically in the java files. Maybe could you post your manifest in your question?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have tried that too to no avail.

Comment: Hmm... Do you have to have that receiver in your manifest? Or could you try having it in your java files? Or have you tried it in your java files to no avail?

Comment: Perhaps I need to put the receiver in the manifest - like the attach filter, it won't work if done in code.  I will try that and get back.

Comment: Okay, putting the receiver in the manifest fixes the problem.  Thanks for the help!